# connect to local computer while on VPN

Tags: windows-10, vpn, home-networking, cisco-anyconnect

While I'm connected to VPN I want to be able to connect to a machine in my home network (i.e. for remote desktop of SSH)

The problem is that even pinging to local machines times out and ping to the router results in `General failure`

Is it even possible - access local machine while connected to VPN?

**Edit**

```
Tunnel Mode (IPv4): Tunnel All Traffic
Tunnel Mode (IPv6): Tunnel All Traffic
Dynamic Tunnel Exclusion: None
```

I guess I can't change those properties - bummer

Comment: It probably depends on the VPN app itself. Most should allow connection to the local network, some even offer per-app routing, so some apps go via the VPN & some direct.

Comment: Can you do a VPN split connection? It might help.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen Im not very femiliar with that option - I'll search for it

Comment: @Sickest I've tagged it - cisco-anyconnect

Comment: I'm using ExpressVPN. tbh I don't know if the functionality is in the app or the service, but it feels like it's the app itself, as the split is taking place right in my machine, macOS Mojave, without any assistance from my router/gateway [which is also capable of VPN, but not in use right now] It's not something I'd know how to set up manually, but it is demonstrably possible. I had need to test out 5 or 6 different VPN solutions only yesterday & all were capable of local as well as VPN routing, though only Express has the per-app functionality of the ISP/VPN choice.

Comment: Since you're using AnyConnect, can you show its settings/status screens? There should be an option specifically about allowing local LAN access, is that enabled?

Comment: @grawity - I can't change nothing in the vpn client. I guesst I'll find a workaround

Comment: Those are not the settings I was asking about. There is a checkbox in the configuration tab that _specifically_ deals with LAN access. (If there isn't one, your sysadmin has hidden it in the profile.)

Comment: If the VPN app was configured by your admin it will probably be locked down, so that you cannot change the config. What you are looking for is called 'split tunneling' where only traffic for the remote (company's) network is sent to the VPN tunnel. Your admin will have deliberately prevented this for fear of data leakage or intrusion. To solve this, you will have to talk to him/her to have the (locked) configuration of the VPN client changed.